# How to add new xml in sql 2008 xml column

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table (`myTable`) with a column that holds configurations in `xml` formatting. I need to add a new setting to one of the nodes but I can't find how to add it and then find it and see if it was added correctly. this xml column is very big so it's hard to add it manually. Any help would be appreciated.

`<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" IsTemplate="false">
    <Adapter Name="[dbo].[Customer]">
       <Col name="LastName" type="varchar" size="100" param="@P_1" />
       <Col name="FirstName" type="varchar" size="100" null="true" param="@P_2" />
       <Col name="MiddleInitial" type="nvarchar" size="1" null="true" param="@P_3" />
       <Col name="Address" type="varchar" size="500" null="true" param="@P_4" />
       <Col name="City" type="varchar" size="100" null="true" param="@P_5" />
       <Col name="State" type="varchar" size="20" null="true" param="@P_6" />
       <!--Add New Col here-->
       <Col name="PostalCode" type="varchar" size="20" null="true" param="@P_7" />
    </Adapter>
</Configuration>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking pieces from other queries I think I finally got it to work.

```
DECLARE @table VARCHAR (max) 
SET @table = '[dbo].[Customer]' 
DECLARE @Column VARCHAR (max) 
SET @Column = 'test1'
```

> --Insert the record.

```
UPDATE Sync. scope_config
SET config_data. modify('insert <Col name="test1" type="bit" null="true" param="@P_000" />
after
(/Configuration/Adapter[@Name=sql:variable("@table")]/Col[@name=sql:variable("@Column")])[1]')
WHERE config.config_data.exist('/Configuration/Adapter[@Name=sql:variable("@table")]' ) = 1
```

> --Find the record.

```
SELECT  s.config_data. query('(/Configuration/Adapter[@Name=sql:variable("@table")])' ) 
from dbo.config s
WHERE s.config_data. exist('/Configuration/Adapter[@Name=sql:variable("@table")]/Col[@name=sql:variable("@Column")]' ) = 1
```